Filtering with Attributes - how to display all non-queried products below query
I addded attributes to filter out products, based on their selection. For instance, I have field named 'tiled' as yes or no. If person ticks 'yes', all the products with the attribute of 'yes' are shown. All of the products with the attribute of 'no', are not displayed.
How can I display all of the products that are not filtered BELOW the filtered query (ie: showing all of the products with 'No' below the product filter)?
Inside of my functions.php file, I believe this is how the filtered products are queried:
function sort_products_by_positive_attributes($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce()) {
        // First, you would need to get all products along with their positive attributes count
        $products_with_scores = [];
         if (!empty($query->posts)) {
        foreach ($query->posts as $post) {
            $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
            $score = get_product_positive_attributes_count($product);
            $products_with_scores[$post->ID] = $score;
        }
        }else {

        }
        // Then you would sort products by their score
        uasort($products_with_scores, function($a, $b) {
            return $b - $a;
        });

        // After sorting, modify the query to order by the IDs in the sorted order
        $sorted_ids = array_keys($products_with_scores);
        $query->set('orderby', 'post__in');
        $query->set('post__in', $sorted_ids);

        /*  
          Query that displays non-filtered products goes here

          EDIT: Possible to make an inverted $sorted_ids?     
          Do second $query here with opposite $sorted_ids?
        */

    }
}
//add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sort_products_by_positive_attributes');

function get_product_positive_attributes_count($product) {
    // You would implement the logic here to count the number of positive attributes
    $score = 0;
    // for each attribute, if it's positive, increment $score
    return $score;
}



To display products that do not match the filter ("No" products) below the filtered products ("Yes" products), you can modify your query logic to retrieve both filtered and unfiltered products in a single operation. Here's how to implement it:

Steps:

Modify the Query Logic:

Create two queries: one for filtered products ("Yes") and another for unfiltered products ("No").
Merge the results so that "Yes" products appear first, followed by "No" products.


Implementation:
Use custom query parameters and manipulate the results before passing them back to WooCommerce.



Updated Code:
Here’s how your sort_products_by_positive_attributes function can be updated:
function sort_products_by_positive_attributes($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce()) {
        // Get all products matching the filter (e.g., 'tiled' = 'yes')
        $filtered_args = [
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // Adjust as needed
            'meta_query' => [
                [
                    'key' => 'tiled', // Replace 'tiled' with your custom field key
                    'value' => 'yes',
                    'compare' => '='
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $filtered_query = new WP_Query($filtered_args);

        // Get all products NOT matching the filter (e.g., 'tiled' = 'no')
        $unfiltered_args = [
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // Adjust as needed
            'meta_query' => [
                [
                    'key' => 'tiled', // Replace 'tiled' with your custom field key
                    'value' => 'no',
                    'compare' => '='
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $unfiltered_query = new WP_Query($unfiltered_args);

        // Combine the results: Filtered products first, then unfiltered
        $merged_posts = array_merge($filtered_query->posts, $unfiltered_query->posts);

        // Set the query posts and post count
        $query->posts = $merged_posts;
        $query->post_count = count($merged_posts);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sort_products_by_positive_attributes');


Explanation:

Filtered Query:

Retrieves products where the meta field tiled is set to yes.
Replace 'tiled' with the actual meta key for your field.


Unfiltered Query:

Retrieves products where the meta field tiled is set to no.


Merge Results:

Combines the two sets of posts, placing the filtered products first.
The merged list is then assigned to $query->posts.


Pagination Support (Optional):

If you’re using pagination, you’ll need to handle it manually by slicing $merged_posts based on paged and posts_per_page.




Debugging Tips:

Use error_log(print_r($query->posts, true)); to verify the merged results.
Ensure the custom field tiled is correctly assigned to your products in the WooCommerce product meta.

This approach ensures that all products are displayed, with the filtered products at the top and the unfiltered ones below. Let me know if further adjustments are needed!

Thank you Richard for your in-depth help. Unfortunately, it didn't do much. It still ran correctly with no errors which is a start.

Would it be possible to do a second, inverted $sorted_ids, just below the first one and doing a $query the same way as above, but with the inverted $sorted_ids. Is that possible?
